# AsyncTask - after execution, how to update view?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In the onCreate() event of an Activity, I have started an AsyncTask to retrieve Product data from a database. After this has been completed successfully, how can I update the display?

Metacode:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.venueviewbasic);
            (..)
    new GetProductDetails().execute();

class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", vid));
        (.. retrieve and parse data and set new textview contents ..)
```

The textviews etc. don't get updated however.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to update the view from async after complete process in then
you can use

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        textView.setText(result);
    }
```

But if you want to update data while running background process then use.
For ex...

```
protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));<------
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {  <-------
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }
```

for more detail see [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
Hope this will help you...!

Comment: great, I will consider that to update my rather long listview somewhere else, for now the first part did the trick. Thanks! :)

Comment: I get `myTextView cannot be resolved` if I try `myTextView.setText(result);`. And  I get `The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type MyClass` if I try to load the UI .

Answer (score 11):

I am guessing the question is more about how to get hold of the UI View if the asyncTask is in a separate file .

In that case you have to pass the context to the Async task and use that to get the view.

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

    Activity mActivity;

    public MyAsyncTask(Activity activity) {
       mActivity = ativity;
    }
```

And then in your onPostExecute use

```
int id = mActivity.findViewById(...);
```

Remember you cannot update the View from "doInBackground" since its not the UI thread.

Answer (score 5):

In your `AsyncTask` class, add a `onPostExecute` method. This method executes on the UI thread and can update any UI component. 

`class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<...> 
{
    ...
    private TextView textView;
    ...
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        textView.setText(result);
    }
}`

(The `result` parameter is the value returned from the `doInBackground` method of your class.)

Comment: exactly, that did the trick, thanks!! I have to update the display in the onPostExecute() method rather than directly in the thread.

Comment: I get `myTextView cannot be resolved` if I try `myTextView.setText(result);`. And  I get `The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type MyClass` if I try to load the UI .

Comment: Did you get your answer  @FranciscoCorralesMorales. I am getting the same issue

Comment: @Yasha see Abhik's answer below. In the constructor of your async task, pass in the instance of the Activity that you want (e.g. MainActivity mainActivity).