# Android: How do I create loading screen while access the database

Tags: android

I have been developing one Map project. In all Activity classes i have one method called **getDataFromServer()** which parse some JSON Response from the server for the particular activity. And displays that data on the Map. While receiving and parse data , I want to display loading screen. How to make getDataFromServer() method in Doinbackground().

Please provide me the best way........
Thanks..

Comment: use `AsyncTaks` see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10570414/1289716

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

```
public final class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Boolean> {

private Context context;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public DownloadFile (Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

/* 
 * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
 */
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    try {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "message", true);
    } catch (final Throwable th) {
        //TODO
    }
}

/* 
 * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
 */
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    //do something
}

    @Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    //do something
    super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
}

/* 
 * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
} }
```

Comment: How i call doInBackGround() inside the button on click

Comment: you should call the task like: new DownloadFile(ActivityName.this).execute(); this will automatically call doInBackground() method..

Comment: @Ninu I have got runtime exception

Comment: cant create handler inside the thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: i create DownloadFile as Inner class

Comment: this exception means, you are calling code that updates the UI inside doInBackground() you should call it in onPreExecute or onPostExecute

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14270/discussion-between-sridhar-and-nunu)

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link

http://www.bango29.com/go/blog/2011/android-asynctask-is-a-beauty-part-2

In button on clicklistener, you can create object.

new Classname().execute();