# Should I use AsyncTask to fill 30+ TextViews?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, thread-safety

I'm using **Loaders** to get a JSON from server...
everything are working...

Now I need put all this **values** in many **TextViews**...
When **onLoadFinished** is called, I'm using:

```
miTextView1.setText(value1);
miTextView2.setText(value2);
//and so on...
```

Should I use Asynctask to fill all these TextViews?

Comment: I think you have to call that from the ui thread, so try them normally.

Comment: you can do it @ `onPostexecute()` of the asyncTask that fetches the data from server, you can't touch UI from doInBackground()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used AsyncTask for things like this before, with good results. You can set your TextViews with default text like "Pending . . ." (bonus points for figuring out some sort of text animation) and then update them in `onPostExecute` once you have the data. See Tony the Pony's SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570243/asynctask-after-execution-how-to-update-view) for the basic code pattern.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask is used to run short term background tasks.

UI can not update with AsyncTask.

You need to do it with Handler in Android.